# Rest API c Maven - игнорируется запрос DELETE

Tags: java-ee, maven, rest, jersey

Есть Dynamic Web Project - Java EE7 проект REST API на Эклипсе.
Реализовал его с Jersey и сервером Tomcat 8.5. Все работает, но вот потребовалось запускать проще, используя `mvn exec:java`.

Скачал Apache Maven 3.5.2, не думая сделал такое:

`mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.wkwn -DartifactId=rest-example-Dpackage=com.wkwn.rest.example -DarchetypeVersion=2.22.2`

Попробовал `mvn clean compile` и `mvn install`в создавшейся папке *rest-example* - успешно.
Далее открыл в IntellIj IDEA эту папку, раскоментил в pom.xml строчку для поддержки JSON, накидал в проект свои файлы *.java со старого проекта, подправил лишь возвращаемые значения.

Запуск. **Все запросы необходимо отправлять в JSON-формате.**

Отправляю запросы: **GET**, **POST** и **PUT** работают корректно, а **DELETE** вообще не видит как будто, хотя он есть! Присутствует он и в сгенерированном localhost:8080/**application.wadl** файле.
Просто на запрос **DELETE** приходит пустой ответ "**Response 400 Bad Request**" (отправляю запросы в RESTer - расширение для браузера).

Запрос составлен корректно, для примера даже обычный `return "Hello world!";` не видит. Больше скажу, при дебаге, в функцию запроса DELETE даже не заходит!

На всякий случай кину Main, хотя он автоматически построился:

```
package com.wkwn.rest.notes;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;


public class Main {
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/";

    public static HttpServer startServer() {

        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.wkwn.rest.notes");

        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final HttpServer server = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено:

```
server.getServerConfiguration().setAllowPayloadForUndefinedHttpMethods(true);
```